# flutter_math_fork dependency keeps adding itself back to project - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io

I added flutter_math_fork to my project but after now I don't have any use of it. I have removed it from pubspec.yaml but it still shows here

```
Resolving dependencies...
flutter_math_fork 0.5.0 (0.7.1 available)
```

and after updating flutter to latest version `3.10.6` it shows this error when build

```
/C:/Users/syedi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:186:20:
Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
- 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/D:/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
```

and not just `onTapDown` the same error shows 5 more times for `onSingleTapUp`, `onDoubleTapDown`, `onDragSelectionStart`, `onDragSelectionUpdate`, `onDragSelectionEnd`.

I have tried downgrading my flutter version and the errors solves but I have new dependencies which requires flutter `3.10.6`.

My pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
  switch_tab: ^0.1.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.2
  images_picker: ^1.2.11
  circle_progress_bar: ^0.1.2
  timeago: ^3.3.0
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.1
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
  date_time_format: ^2.0.1
  camera: ^0.10.5+2
  image_picker: ^0.8.9
  lottie: ^2.3.2
  flutter_tex: ^4.0.3+1
  flutter_tts: ^3.6.3
  crop_your_image: ^0.7.2
  permission_handler: ^10.4.3
  agora_uikit: ^1.3.4
```

Comment: running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` didn't work?

Comment: yes didn't work, I also tried deleting pubspec.lock file but It didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flutter_html: ^2.2.1` depends on `flutter_math_fork`, so you also need to remove `flutter_html: ^2.2.1`.
It is not compatible with Flutter 3.10.6. [flutter_html 2.2.1 dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EsA4.png) 
Or you can try the beta version: [flutter_html 3.0.0-beta.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/versions/3.0.0-beta.2), It works with Flutter 3.10.6.